# AngularJS angular expressions in google maps embed url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, google-maps

I'm trying to introduce coordinates into a google maps embed from angular expressions without success.

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h2 class="panel-title">Location map: {{vm.data.location.coords[1]}}, {{vm.data.location.coords[0]}}</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <iframe width="100%" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0" ng-src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q={{vm.data.location.coords[1]}},{{vm.data.location.coords[0]}}&zoom=9&key=MYAPIKEY" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

In the above code, you can see that I'm introducing the coordinates inside an H2 tag, where coordinates are shown without problems. But when I introduce the same code to the URL, it do not display, And all angular expressions are shown as text. The url works perfectly when you introduce numerical values.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you add a Fiddle?